# Can I combine two separate linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's assume I want to calculate maximum achievable speed of a car with the following assumptions:

1. Speed depends on car weight (lower weight = higher speed), e.g. Speed = 0.142*weight + 21
2. Speed depends on air density (lower density = higher speed), e.g. Speed = 15.7*density - 0.258

Each of these two factors plays a role in the car's speed. Is it possible to create a single equation where both weight and density would be taken into account so I could do one calculation with e.g. Weight = A and Density = B to get the result?

Comment: Is the first expression, for the speed in terms of the weight, valid only for *one particular value* of the air density? And is the second valid only for *one particular value* of the weight?

Comment: Yes - correct. Weight equation is valid for one particular value of air density and air density equation is valid for one particular value of weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given two different expressions for the speed. One depends purely on the weight, the other depends purely on the density. In particular, the first expression tells you that the speed does *not*

For brevity I'll denote the speed, weight and air density by $v$, $m$ and $\rho$. Then you have the expressions
\begin{eqnarray*}
v&=&0.142m+21\qquad&\text{ if }\qquad& \rho&=&\rho_0,\\
v&=&15.7\rho-0.258\qquad&\text{ if }\qquad& m&=&m_0,
\end{eqnarray*}
that each hold for a particular air density $\rho_0$ and a particular weight $m_0$. Now you would like an expression
$$v=f(m,\rho),$$
for all value of $m$ and $\rho$. This would define $v$ on the entire $(m,\rho)$-plane. But you have only defined $v$ on the two lines $\rho=\rho_0$ and $m=m_0$, which are a horizontal and a vertical line. From this geometric picture it should be clear that there is no unique way to extend from these lines to the entire plane.

However, if you make some strong assumptions on what $f$ should look like, then there may be a unique extension. For example, if you assume that $f$ is linear in $m$ and $\rho$ then we must have
$$f(m,\rho)=c_0+c_1m+c_2\rho+c_3m\rho,$$
for some constants $c_i$. Then plugging in $\rho=\rho_0$ and $m=m_0$ yields a system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray*}
0.142m+21&=&f(m,\rho_0)&=&(c_0+c_2\rho_0)+(c_1+c_3\rho_0)m,\\
15.7\rho-0.258&=&f(m_0,\rho)&=&(c_0+c_1m_0)+(c_2+c_3m_0)\rho,
\end{eqnarray*}
which you can then solve for the $c_i$: As these two equations hold for *all* $m$ and $\rho$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
21&=&c_0+c_2\rho_0,\\
0.142&=&c_1+c_3\rho_0,\\
-0.258&=&c_0+c_1m_0,\\
15.7&=&c_2+c_3m_0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then it is a matter of linear algebra to solve for the $c_i$.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is very clear - I felt intuitively what you describred by "there is no unique way to extend from these lines to the entire plane", but I wasn't able to prove it. 
Then my next question would be - how can I solve for the "ci"? I still have too many unknown variables in the two equations...?

Comment: @user2165039 These two equations hold for *all* $m$ and $\rho$, so in a sense you have infinitely many equations in four variables (I'm treating $\rho_0$ and $m_0$ as known constants). I have added an explanation of how to solve for the $c_i$.

Comment: Thanks again. I have tried solving this with my actual numbers and equations and the outcome is there is that no solution exists. What does it say - does it e.g. mean that f is not linear in weight and density which was the assumption that allowed us to create the 4-equation system?

Comment: Exactly; apparently no such $c_i$ exist, so $f$ is not of this form. Perhaps some reasoning from the physics can suggest what form $f$ should take, but that does not seem like a question for this site. Perhaps physics.se?

Comment: This does suggest that you have more data that just the two equations and $m_0$ and $\rho_0$. Could you include all relevant information in your question? Also the values of $m_0$ and $\rho_0$?

Comment: My equations are v = 0.00646*m + 19.4 for r=2200 and v = 0.0182*r+0.491 for m=3200

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much more useful information that I could share publicly except for having those two linear equations describing the function which depends on two variables in two different ways. I would be able to obtain another two equations for different values of r0 and m0 if that could be used to obtain a solution.

Comment: The two equations don't agree; at $(m,r)=(3200,2200)$ you get two different values for $v$.